# How to do make my variable a color in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, colorama

```
print("Question 1:") #Question 1
    
print("KPH \t MPH")
for KPH in range(60,131,10): #range km/h
    print(KPH,format(KPH*0.6214,"10.1f"))
```

This program takes a range of speeds in km/h (60-130) and converts them to to mph.  I cant figure out how to make the km/h one color and the miles/h another color.  Could someone please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal

Comment: @pavelsaman i have tried that but since i am  trying to add color to a variable it gives me an error.

Comment: What error gives you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use color codes found [here](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html)

For example:

```py
print("Question 1:")  # Question 1

RED = "\u001b[31m"
CYAN = "\u001b[36m"

print(f"{RED}KPH \t {CYAN}MPH")
for KPH in range(60, 131, 10):  # range km/h
    print(RED + str(KPH), CYAN + format(KPH * 0.6214, "10.1f"))
```